# 200+ Warnings JWplayer Mobile SDK iOS Xcode

Tags: xcode, jwplayer

Prerequisites:

- Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)
- CocoaPods 0.39.0
- `pod 'JWPlayer-SDK', :inhibit_warnings => true`

When I set `Debug Information Format` to Dwarf the warnings disappear

But it's only necessary for the JWPlayer SDK, so please fix it.

[image]

> while processing
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/myproject/Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWPictureInPictureHandler.o):
>   warning:
>   /var/folders/53/y97w7fr55sjc262qprp8lby80000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.jenkins/ModuleCache/P0EAZ51IY1Y2/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm:
>   No such file or directory while processing
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/myproject/Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWPictureInPictureHandler.o):
>   warning:
>   /var/folders/53/y97w7fr55sjc262qprp8lby80000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.jenkins/ModuleCache/P0EAZ51IY1Y2/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm:
>   No object file for requested architecture while processing
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/myproject/Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWPictureInPictureHandler.o):
>   warning:
>   /var/folders/53/y97w7fr55sjc262qprp8lby80000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.jenkins/ModuleCache/P0EAZ51IY1Y2/AVKit-95365SBJXV2.pcm:
>   No such file or directory

Podlock doesn't give me a version number, but I include the pod like this :

> pod 'JWPlayer-SDK'

According to CocoaPods page it's JWPlayer-SDK 2.1.0 (https://cocoapods.org/pods/JWPlayer-SDK)

Comment: what jwplayer-sdk version is that?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko I've updated my question

Comment: strange. try to update the pod.